# How can a C# List<IList> accept a List<T> but not an IList<T> when creating the collection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a collection of collections, like a 2D array.
Each collection (inside the main collection) will be the same type, though. It's just that we don't know what those types are.

for example:

a collection that contains:
- a list of cats
- a list of houses
- a list of SO questions.

so a collection with 3x collections inside.

Now, I'm trying the following C# code and getting a compile time error when I'm trying to do this:

```
IList<Foo> foos1 = new List<Foo>(); // e.g. Cats.
List<Foo> foos2= new List<Foo>(); // e.g. Houses.

var fails = new List<IList>
{
   foos1 // Fails
};

var works = new List<IList>
{
   foos2 // Works
};
```

Can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why _should_ the `fails` example not fail? The list element type is `IList`. And `IList<Foo>` does not implement/inherit `IList`. So you're trying to put an object of an incompatible type into the list. The whole point of generics is **so that exactly that scenario won't work**. Why do you need any sort of explanation for that? I can only surmise that your question really is why doesn't the generic `IList<T>` not inherit `IList`. For that, see duplicate.

Comment: `IList<T>` is covariant, `List<T>` is not. It's a limitation of C# right now that they'll fix eventually.

Comment: @Dai - That's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Enigmativity My mistake - I'll admit that I didn't read the question, I just glanced at the code and assumed that was the problem :)

Comment: @Dai - Yeah, that was my first thought. Then I realised that the OP was making lists of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IList<T>` implements the following interfaces: `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IEnumerable`.

`List<T>` implements the following interfaces `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`, `IList`, `ICollection`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

So an `IList<T>` cannot be cast to an `IList`, but a `List<T>` can.